# writing junit for custom spring validator class

Tags: spring, junit, validation

How to write a unit testing case for custom spring validator implementation class . For example

public class RegistrationValidator implements Validator.

Just wanted to know the various approaches . Am new to spring so exploring all options.

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Errors object,
Create an instance of your Validator,

invoke yourValidator(testData, errors)

Check that Errors is modified in the way you expected, in dependence to `testData`

```
@Test
public void testValidateWithUserWithoutLogin() {
    User u = new User(); //your domain object, for example a user with "login=null"

    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(u, "u");

    MyValidator validator = newValidator();

    validator.validate(p, errors);  // 'validator' under test

    assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
    assertNotNull( errors.getFieldError("login") );
}
```

*BTW: you should have a look at JSR 303-Bean Validation, it is also supported by Spring 3.0. But it is easyer to use (less code) for the most use cases.*

Comment: Thanks alot :) i am able to write junit classes with this example

Comment: How is it supposed to use group validation here?

Comment: @jaranda: This question and answer is about Spring Validator (`org.springframework.validation.Validator`) not about (`javax.validation.Validator`). Spring Validator does not have a Group concept.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for pointing it out; any clues on how to test a custom spring validator when using groups? This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744988/writing-junit-tests-for-spring-validator-implementation) works with no group specified. Is it actually possible?