# Spring - Instantiating an Errors object

Tags: java, spring

I have a method like this:

```
public boolean validateMessage(String message, Errors errors) {
  if (!StringUtils.hasLength(message)) {
    errors.rejectValue(wrapperName + "message", "EMPTY_MESSAGE", EMPTY_MESSAGE_ERRORMSG) ;
            return false ;
        }
        return true ;
    }
```

I want to call this method with a new `Errors` object, like:

```
boolean result = validateMessage("hi", new Errors()) ;
```

However, this kind of instantiation is not allowed for `Errors`. Please advice.

If not with `Errors`, can I achieve this using an empty (new) `BindingResult`

Comment: You can not instatiate an interface. `BindException`, `EscapedErrors` are the implementing classes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744988/writing-junit-tests-for-spring-validator-implementation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Errors` and `BindingResult` are interfaces, therefore they cannot be instantiated. Your only option would be to use one of the classes which implements `Errors`.

You could use `org.springframework.validation.BindException`, this implements `Errors` - [see here for details](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html).

Comment: that does not work because `BindException` cannot be cast to `Errors`

Comment: If I try casting it, I get this: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.BindException cannot be cast to org.springframework.validation.Errors`. So obviously, it's not possible.

Comment: org.springframework.validation.BindException implements Errors, so it should be possible.

Comment: `BindException` can be cast as it implements Errors.  You are instantiating the wrong `BindException` class - it is not a `java.net.BindException` object - it is `org.springframework.validation.BindException`

Comment: java.net.BindException is the wrong class, you need the one outlined in my above comment.

Comment: oops, totally my Bad. I've changed it and it works :) Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: @Jonathan pls edit your answer so that I can cancel the downvote. I'm really sorry :(

Comment: @th3an0maly no problem, I had completely forgotten about the other BindException.

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to use org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult, which implements Errors. This object is of the same class of the BindingResult you recieve in Spring MVC controllers

```
Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(objectToValidate, "objectName");
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, you can not initialize an object of Errors since this is an interface.

I am trying to initialize the Errors object for my JUnit test cases. There are many implementation available of Errors in Spring, (I have attached one picture below).

I tried `new EscapedErrors(null)`, but it's constructor itself expects Errors object to be passed.

**Solution**:
The constructor of `org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult` looks like below:

```java
public BeanPropertyBindingResult(Object target, String objectName) {
        this(target, objectName, true, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
```

So for me, `Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(new Object(), "dummy");` works like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most of times developers use `@Valid` and `BindingResult` to validate the posted or new object. For instance in the following code validates the **Category** object via `@Valid` annotation and then binds its result with `BindingResult`. But all these steps are done by `Spring` automatically.

```
@PostMapping
public String saveCategory(@Valid Category category, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    // if there are some errors
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        for (ObjectError objectError : bindingResult.getAllErrors())
        {
            System.out.println(objectError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Although the above-mentioned code snippet is one of the outstanding advantages of Spring, occasionally you want the same behaviors in the other layers. So you must get an instance of implemented form of BindingResult and inject a Validator to your code:

```
...
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
...

@Service
public class CategoryService
{

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
    ...

    private void insertNewCategory(Category category)
    {
        BindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(category, "objectName");
        validator.validate(category, bindingResult);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors())
            {
                System.out.println(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can instantiate class objects. but `Errors` is an interface, not a class. hence, it cannot be instantiated like you are trying to do.

Comment: But there should be some way around this. Are you saying what I'm trying to do is impossible? :(

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Spring MVC application and you are using @Controllers you can pass your validation object in the form of `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult` as part of the mapping as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value="login.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, BindingResult errors) {
    // ..... some validation code

    String message = "My message";
    boolean valid = validateMessage(message, errors); 

    // .... some more code
}
```

This is an alternative way of to having explicitly instantiating `org.springframework.validation.Errors`.

Answer (score 0):

The method is expecting an Object which implements the `Errors` interface.  Any class implementing the Errors interface would work.  If you do not want to use an existing class such as `org.springframework.validation.BindException`, you can use an anonymous inner class.  See [the Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) for existing classes which already implement `Errors`. But your anonymous class would need to implement all the interface methods, which are quite numerous and makes your code increasingly difficult to read:

```
boolean result = validateMessage( "hi", new Errors() {

        @Override
        public void setNestedPath(String nestedPath) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, Object[] errorArgs, String defaultMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void reject(String errorCode, Object[] errorArgs, String defaultMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void reject(String errorCode, String defaultMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void reject(String errorCode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void pushNestedPath(String subPath) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void popNestedPath() throws IllegalStateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasGlobalErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasFieldErrors(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasFieldErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getObjectName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getNestedPath() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ObjectError> getGlobalErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGlobalErrorCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectError getGlobalError() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getFieldValue(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Class getFieldType(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<FieldError> getFieldErrors(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<FieldError> getFieldErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getFieldErrorCount(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getFieldErrorCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public FieldError getFieldError(String field) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public FieldError getFieldError() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getErrorCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ObjectError> getAllErrors() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void addAllErrors(Errors errors) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    } );
```

Comment: Exactly the reason why I was looking for an alternative

Comment: You can always create your own MyError class (either as an inner class or package private or even public class) and instantiate that when you want to use it.  I've also edited my response to include a link to Spring docs which list other Spring classes which implement the Errors interface