# Spring boot: should validation been tested when testing controller layer

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, spring-validator

I am working on the project where I want to have decent test-infrastructure.
I am using spring boot, which makes easier for testing separate layers of the project: for example

If I want to test controller layer I will mock (with mockito) service dependencies of the controller, and check whether right service method will be called on given http request, and expected http status will be returned. If I want to test service layer I will mock repository and business logic dependencies. And so on.

In my project, I am using spring validators to check whether request body is passed correctly (with the use of @InitBinder method I am adding my custom validators to the WebDataBinder, and with use of @Valid annotation, those validators are called on the parsed request body).

So my question is: is it good practice to mock validators and test only controller logic (validators will be tested in context of validator layer)?
I am just not sure which is the best practice, and is it normal to test validators along with controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is not always best option, when you are testing your controller logic, validation logic and especially business logic. I would not recommend to mock any of these.

You can use various framework to test:

1. Controller logic - RestAssured or MockMvc
2. Business logic - Plain JUnit tests under *SpringBootTest* and *SpringRunner*
3. Validation logic - Plain JUnit tests under *SpringBootTest* and
   *SpringRunner*

For further reading: 
**RestAssured**: http://rest-assured.io/ 
**Spring validator test**: [Writing JUnit tests for Spring Validator implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744988/writing-junit-tests-for-spring-validator-implementation)

Comment: Personally, I think, that testing project layers separately is a good practice, and mocking helps to achieve this (If you have an object-oriented design, which correctly keeps "Dependency Inversion" design principle). I agree with 3 points that you have mentioned. But to test controller layer separated from validation layer (like you have suggested in points 1 and 3), you will need to mock validators which are used by the controller, and this was my question: "is it a good practice to mock validators to test controller layer separately?"

Comment: My answer is to not to mock validators in controller layer, if you use RestAssured

Comment: If I understood correctly from the RestAssured documentation, this technique will not only test controller layer but the whole logic under the endpoint, so it will become production test, not just unit test for the layer. Of-coarse I will have some production tests separately and maybe I will use RestAssured for that purpose, but before that, I would like to test controller layer independent of the other layer. If I understood you correctly you are suggesting to not even mock services, with which I disagree. But I guess its personal preference. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hi haykart, how did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem. I'm testing my Application Web Layer with @WebMvcTest. I don't want it to connect to a database because doing that is not unit testing.